# How to show a percentage of another value on a pie chart? Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to make a pie chart based of two values: The total number of sales and number of special requests from those total sales.

So if I have 50 sales, but 5 were special requests, the pie chart should show me the 5 as 10% on the 50. But instead, it adds the numbers, using 55 as the total number for the pie chart and showing the 5 and the 50 as parts of it. How can I change this?

Comment: please share sample data and screenshot how exactly you've setup the chart.

Comment: You could provide a sample about your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a very simple fix.  The pie chart represents 100% of your values, in your example 50.  So, if you have 5 special orders (out of 50), you have 45 regular orders.  So, your chart should be based on 45 regular orders + 5 special orders (and not 50+5, which as you've seen, Excel will interpret as 55 total orders).  With those values, Excel will correctly create your chart.